# How to Remove a script with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a problem with my jQuery. So, I want to remove a script who is inside a . My html is :

```
<div id="right-bloc">
        <div class="right-bloc-pub-1">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://firstScript.com"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="right-bloc-pub-2">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://secondScript.com"></script>
        </div>
</div>
```

I find the solution which is below

```
html.find('script[src="http://firstScript.com"]').remove();
```

But the problem is it only removes the script which only has HTTP URL because some script has that kind of URL

```
//ialtears.com/d2/32/42/d23949fadf7b59629f8345.js
```

I want to remove that kind of URL's

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```js
JQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('script').each(function() {
          this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
});
```